# Having an image and paragraph inline

Tags: html, css, layout, css-position

I want to position a paragraph and an image next to each other and have them both centered. Here is an example of what I'm trying to do. Scroll down a bit to see.

http://shibori-demo.squarespace.com/how-shibori-works-shibori/

I can get this to work but it all is squished up to the left side of the 
viewport. What's the best way to get this effect?

Comment: wrap them in a div. center that div.

Answer (score 2):

The example you gave used flex properties. In a nutshell, you can accomplish your task by putting your elements inside a div container with display:flex.

```
<div class="container">
  <p class="inner">text, texty texty text. Text text text, texty texty text. Text text text, texty texty text. Text text text, texty texty text. Text text text, texty texty text. Text text text, texty texty text. Text text text, texty texty text. Text text text, texty texty text. Text text text, texty texty text. Text text text, texty texty text. 
  </p>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x350"/>
</div>
```

The css is simple:

```
 .container {
      display: flex;
    }
```

Here's a complete guide to [flex](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) and the doc to the [display](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) property.

After that, change the width to whatever you need and center it.

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

DIVs. Lots of divs.

First, and outer div that is `width:100%` and is `text-align:center`

Then, a wrapper div to put the two items in. It should be styled `overflow:hidden` so that the inner divs (styled using float) have height.

Finally, a div around each item to give them their own box, and style each as `float:left`

```css
div {position:relative;box-sizing:border-box;}
.wrapper{width:100%;border:1px solid orange;}
  .innerwrap{width:100%;overflow:hidden;}
    .boxes{float:left;width:50%;padding:10px;}
    .leftBox {}
    .rightBox{}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="innerwrap">
    <div class="boxes leftBox">
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/230/300" />
    </div>
    <div class="boxes rightBox">
      <p>Ad vidit contentiones consequuntur sea, quod eripuit assentior an nec. Cu errem eruditi est, quando everti duo eu. Eum consul noster vocent ex, at ius viris aeterno omittam. His nonumy lobortis convenire ei. Sea eu justo choro qualisque. Dolore pertinax accommodare quo et, per ad debet delenit splendide. Voluptua sapientem id eos.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```